# Android notification PendingIntent open activity per notification click

Tags: android

I'm currently doing some notifications for my app. Now I've successfully created a notification but problem is that each of my notification doesn't pass different extras on click.

Well what happen is that I only have a loop that calls the createNotification method per loop and also I assign different ID's for those for the notification to appear in different stack.

here's my code:

```
private void createNotification(String record_name, String file_path, String status, int id) {
        /*must pass:
        * record_name, (get the record name in DB using the id create a new query method)
        * record_status, (simple part just match if equivalent to ready to download for the JSON data then show notif if true)
        * record_path *full path* (this one can be get using the record name itself add the path and extension name)*/

        /*this will jump from the current activity into the target activity class just do some workarounds here*/
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecordEditActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("record_name", record_name);
        intent.putExtra("record_path", file_path);
        intent.putExtra("record_status", status);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, intent, 0); 


        /*build the notification here this is only supported for API 11. Since we've targeted API 11 there will be no problem on this*/
        NotificationCompat.Builder notify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(record_name + " is ready for download")
                .setContentText("Click to view or download recording")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setTicker("Echo: your file is ready for download")
                .setContentIntent(pIntent); 


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<16){
            /*build notification for HoneyComb to ICS*/
            notificationManager.notify(id, notify.getNotification());
        }if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>15){
            /*Notification for Jellybean and above*/
            notificationManager.notify(id, notify.build());
        }

    }
```

I think the problem is in the `PendingIntent` part since I don't know which flags should I use for this but I'm not that sure about it.

Comment: Have you try my answer? Sure it will help you..

Comment: Added a comment on your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it! what needed is for me to assign an ID for my [`pendingIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) requestCode what I did is assign the same ID I used for my notificationManager.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224178/how-to-create-multiple-statusbar-notifications-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

Just use this one line of code-

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And for more detail see this answer: 
[GCM android Push Notification shows old message always. Intent received incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411952/gcm-android-push-notification-shows-old-message-always-intent-received-incorrec)

Comment: Tried this one already what happen is I passed 2 data on my Notification. on my 1st code where the flag is 0 the intent being called is just the 1st data passed on the loop. Lets say I have record2 and record 3. what displayed is 2 notification but both notification redirects me to same activity intent which is record2. After the FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT is applied both notification just redirects me into record3 instead which is not the way I wanted.

Comment: Okay I got..You want both notification right? 1,2,3 and so on right?

Comment: Well to simplify things what I need is for each of my notification to have a correct pending intent. each should be unique. Anyway already got the solution for this. Thanks! :)

Comment: @KaHeL, so please post your solution.

Comment: @EugenePinchuk, it's already posted an hour ago. please see the answer. :)

Comment: @KaHeL, ah sorry, bad wednesday morning )